# Way to find the best performing combination of categorical parameters

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data

I am working with a dataset of 110.000 rows. Each row only has categorical data, most of which is also nominal. Each of these rows represents an event that has several parameters (again, nominal) and an outcome. The question I'm trying to answer is what combination of parameters gives the best result. In this case, the result is the amount of times a combination of parameters is positive or negative.

Because there is no numerical value to work with, I'm not sure what to do. I already calculated the average of each single parameter and also included the standard deviation and did a chi squared test to see what values of a certain parameter are likely to be different from the rest (p<0.05). Now, I mainly want to know what combination of parameters (2 or more) are more likely to have a positive or negative outcome. I'm also planning to use machine learning (decision trees/random forests and neural networks) to give some more insight, but these techniques don't provide an objectively true basis to fall back on.